# JavaScript run without being called in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a `input type="button"`-element as the code shown below as well as a JavaScript in a same page. I try to update my table column after the user presses the button. But the problem is, the JavaScript function is executed without even clicking the button.

Another weird thing happen is, I don't even put

```
onclick="updatePendingStatus()"
```

but the table column still updated

Why is this happening?

My actual goal is, when user click on the button, a query will executed (the code is stated in the JavaScript function)

**View**

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="updatePendingStatus()">

<script type="text/javascript">
function updatePendingStatus()
{ 
  //assume $variable is a variable that send from controller
  {{ App\Furniture::where('id', $variable)->update(['furniture_status' => 5]) }}
}
</script>
```

Comment: by the way updatePendingStatus() function never declare in any js, it is the first time

Comment: You are trying to wrap php within a Javascript function. That's why it runs without the button being pressed, if want this to work you need to look at something like ajax

Comment: any ideas how to do that?

Comment: It's not an easy question to answer because there are several things that you misunderstand and your objective isn't clear, if you change your question to ask how you should achieve your desired result, it will be easier to answer. Also include this as the solution you tried

Comment: i've updated my questions

Comment: Why not just use a simple form submission, instead of that?

Comment: currently i'm using that method, i just wanted to try something more simple to update the table column by avoiding making function in controller :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Easiest way to solve what you are doing is to do a form post. Javascript is run in the web browser while php is run on the server. This means that no php runs on the users computer and that is what you are trying to do. So as soon as all the php on your blade file is run on the server it is doing the update request.

For now do something like this.

HTML

```
<form action="/update_pending_status">
    <button type="submit" button="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

web.php (A file in laravel)

```
Route::post('/update_pending_status', MyController@update_pending_status);
```

MyController.php (Add this function in along with your class declaration).

```
public function update_pending_status() {
    App\Furniture::where('id', $variable)->update(['furniture_status' => 5])
}
```

There will be a page refresh when you do this. Get this working first and then you can look into doing `ajax requests in jquery` if you don't want a page refresh.

Comment: currently i'm doing this method, all works fine...actually i'm trying to avoid making a function in my controller because there is too much controller already

Comment: Make another controller then. If your controller is getting bloated with 1000s of lines of code that means that a bunch of functions are probably getting dumped where they shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a `callback` to `onclick` function, instead of executing it, because the browser will call the `callback` when the button is clicked. But now as soon as it renders the div, the function is executed.

Remove the braces and this should solve your issue.

`onclick="updatePendingStatus"`

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: the js still being executed :(

Comment: are you really sure? It shouldn't happen ideally.